# How to find multiline text in file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that has such a structure:

```
section "first_section" {
  parameter1 = value1
  parameter2 = value2
  parameter3 = value3
}

section "second_section" {
  parameter1 = value1
  parameter2 = value2
  parameter3 = value3
}
...
```

And I have a variable that contains a new section, for example:

```
section "third_section" {
  parameter1 = value1
  parameter2 = value2
  parameter3 = value3
}
```

I'd like to check in Bash before adding a new section if that section already exists in the file.

I was trying something like

```
if grep -q -z "$section" file.txt
then
  echo "Duplicate found"
else
  echo "$section" >> ./file.txt
fi
```

However, I always get a `Duplicate found` output even if it is not true.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code; how was the variable populated (from a file? hardcoded in your script? user input at the command prompt?) (update the question with this additional detail)

Comment: This typically looks like you either want a quick and dirty solution based on regex, which is achievable in Bash, or a more structured parsing-based solution, which is probably more suited for an other language. Which one is the one you are looking for?

Comment: @BlackBeans  quick and dirty solution based on regex is ok for this task. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use bash builtin pattern matching with [the `[[...]]` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b):

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

```bash
contents=$(< filename)
section='section "third" {...}'

if [[ $contents == *"$section"* ]]; then
  echo "file already contains the section"
else
  # append it to the file
  echo "$section" >> filename
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528146/how-to-grep-multi-lines , if your GNU `grep` supports the `P` flag you could do something like:

```
section='section "third_section" {
  parameter1 = value1
  parameter2 = value2
  parameter3 = value3
}'

if grep -qozP  'section "third_section" {(\n.*){1,}}' file.txt; then
  printf 'Duplicate\n' >&2
else
  printf '\n%s' "$section" >> file.txt
fi
```

---

- Assuming *third_section* does not have a duplicate entry with a different entry/contents/values.
- Remove the `-q` flag to see the output of `grep`